# Growing Stack Tkinter (when switching frames)

Tags: python, tkinter, stack-overflow

I've made a Tkinter python app that causes a continually growing stack as the user clicks between frames.  I'm not sure why this happens; I very vaguely understand how a stack works.  Each of the Tkinter frames are objects and I suppose their methods are not actually finishing but calling each other as the user clicks through the program back and forth.

I think this has something to do with how I am using matplotlib, creating figures separate from the Tkinter frames.  Maybe embedding them in the frames would help?

I wonder if how I switch between frames is the problem.  I call `self.controller.show_frame(page_name)` in a method of any frame to switch which frame is raised:

```
def show_frame(self, page_name):
    '''Show a frame for the given page name'''
    frame = self.frames[page_name]
    self.last_frame = self.raised_frame
    self.raised_frame = frame.__name__
    frame.tkraise()

    try:
        frame.re_init()
    except AttributeError as e:
        print_error(e)
```

I could see this `frame.re_init()` method being problematic, but I'd like to update a frame each time it is raised.  It seems to make sense that the stack is growing based on how I call `self.controller.show_frame(page_name)` within each of the Tkinter frame's methods, but I'm not sure what is the better alternative way of switching between Tkinter frames.

It seems this is actually a typical way to switch between frames, so I think problem is with the nonembedded matplotlib figures.

Here is a simple app with the same problem as mine.  Run this and click back and forth a few times.  Watch the terminal output, and you will see how the stack grows.  Need to work with matplotlib animation.

```
import tkinter as tk                # python 3
from tkinter import font  as tkfont # python 3
import traceback
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.animation as animation
import numpy as np
#import Tkinter as tk     # python 2
#import tkFont as tkfont  # python 2

class SampleApp(tk.Tk):

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        tk.Tk.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)

        self.title_font = tkfont.Font(family='Helvetica', size=18, weight="bold", slant="italic")

        # the container is where we'll stack a bunch of frames
        # on top of each other, then the one we want visible
        # will be raised above the others
        container = tk.Frame(self)
        container.pack(side="top", fill="both", expand=True)
        container.grid_rowconfigure(0, weight=1)
        container.grid_columnconfigure(0, weight=1)

        self.frames = {}
        for F in (StartPage, PageOne, PageTwo):
            page_name = F.__name__
            frame = F(parent=container, controller=self)
            self.frames[page_name] = frame

            # put all of the pages in the same location;
            # the one on the top of the stacking order
            # will be the one that is visible.
            frame.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky="nsew")

        self.show_frame("StartPage")

    def show_frame(self, page_name):
        '''Show a frame for the given page name'''
        print("current length of stack: {}".format(len(traceback.extract_stack())))
        frame = self.frames[page_name]
        frame.tkraise()

        try:
            frame.re_init()
        except AttributeError:
            pass

    def do_plot(self):
        plt.close()

        def data_gen(t=0):
            cnt = 0
            while cnt < 1000:
                cnt += 1
                t += 0.1
                yield t, np.sin(2*np.pi*t) * np.exp(-t/10.)


        def init():
            ax.set_ylim(-1.1, 1.1)
            ax.set_xlim(0, 10)
            del xdata[:]
            del ydata[:]
            line.set_data(xdata, ydata)
            return line,

        fig, ax = plt.subplots()
        line, = ax.plot([], [], lw=2)
        ax.grid()
        xdata, ydata = [], []



        def run(data):
            # update the data
            t, y = data
            xdata.append(t)
            ydata.append(y)
            xmin, xmax = ax.get_xlim()

            if t >= xmax:
                ax.set_xlim(xmin, 2*xmax)
                ax.figure.canvas.draw()
            line.set_data(xdata, ydata)

            return line,

        ani = animation.FuncAnimation(fig, run, data_gen, blit=False, interval=10,
                                      repeat=False, init_func=init)

        plt.show()


    def show_plot(self):
        pass

    def stop_plot(self):
        plt.close()


class StartPage(tk.Frame):

    def __init__(self, parent, controller):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)
        self.controller = controller
        label = tk.Label(self, text="This is the start page", font=controller.title_font)
        label.pack(side="top", fill="x", pady=10)

        button1 = tk.Button(self, text="Go to Page One",
                            command=self.one)
        button2 = tk.Button(self, text="Go to Page Two",
                            command=self.two)
        button1.pack()
        button2.pack()

    def one(self):
        self.controller.show_frame("PageOne")

    def two(self):
        self.controller.show_frame("PageTwo")

class PageOne(tk.Frame):

    def __init__(self, parent, controller):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)
        self.controller = controller
        label = tk.Label(self, text="This is page 1", font=controller.title_font)
        label.pack(side="top", fill="x", pady=10)
        button = tk.Button(self, text="Go to the start page",
                           command=lambda: controller.show_frame("StartPage"))
        button.pack()


    def re_init(self):
        self.controller.do_plot()
        self.controller.show_plot()


class PageTwo(tk.Frame):

    def __init__(self, parent, controller):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)
        self.controller = controller
        label = tk.Label(self, text="This is page 2", font=controller.title_font)
        label.pack(side="top", fill="x", pady=10)
        button = tk.Button(self, text="Go to the start page",
                           command=lambda: controller.show_frame("StartPage"))
        button.pack()


    def re_init(self):
        self.controller.do_plot()
        self.controller.show_plot()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = SampleApp()
    app.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 0):

> but I'm not sure what is the better alternative way of switching between Tkinter frames.

In the case where you want to recreate the frame when you switch to it, the better solution is to do exactly that: destroy the old page and have `show_frame` call the function that creates each page

For example, the code where you initialize the window might look like this:

```
class SampleApp(tk.Tk):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        ...
        self.current_page = None
        self.pages = {
            "Page One": PageOne,
            "Page Two": PageTwo,
            "Page Three": PageThree
        }

        # show the first page
        self.show_frame("Page One")
```

`show_frame` would look something like this:

```
def show_frame(self, page_name):
    # remove the old page
    if self.current_page is not None:
        self.current_page.destroy()

    # create the new page
    page_cls = self.pages[page_name]
    self.current_page = page_cls(parent=self.container, controller=self)
    self.current_page.pack(fill="both", expand=True)
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer!  I like this method better for my app.  Unfortunately though, I have implemented it, and the stack issue persists.